# managing permissions between windows and mac git commiters

Tags: windows, git, macos, permissions

The story goes like this...

My team has a git repo on a windows fileserver. A windows guy sets the repo up and begins committing. I, a mac guy, clone to my filesystem, makes some commits, then push back (actually i go to the repo and pull my changes in). The problem is now I own permissions to the files in the repo, and even though I have read/write permissions for everyone in the folder I cloned the repo into, the repo somehow takes on additional permissions restrictions on the windows os and my coworkers cannot commit.

The scenario can play out the other way too. I set up the repo and a windows guy screws up the permissions.

So how are you guys ensuring that permissions are consistent between different development environments?

Comment: Why are going to the windows repo and then `pull`ing? You should have a bare repo hosted somewhere that can be accessed via. ssh or the git protocol. Both parties should then pull/push from/to that repo.

Comment: i agree about the bare repo, but thats not the environment we are working in. We do not use the traditional git set up. Would using a bare repo this way solve my problem?

Comment: @Noufal More specifically, do you have a team made up of windows and mac users who do not have permissions conflicts in the way I describe? Or if you don't, are you aware of a sure fire way to avoid the problems I'm having?

Comment: I collaborate with Mac users (I use Debian myself) but no windows people so I'm not sure. I use a hosted repo on github. The reason I suggested it is because the process managing the connections (ssh etc.) should take care of authentication and permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try the config  `core.sharedRepository`:

```
core.sharedRepository
```

> When group (or true), the repository is made shareable between several users in a group (making sure all the files and objects are group-writable).
>
> - When all (or world or everybody), the repository will be readable by all users, additionally to being group-shareable.
> - When `umask` (or false), git will use permissions reported by `umask`(2).
> - When `0xxx`, where `0xxx` is an octal number, files in the repository will have this mode value. `0xxx` will override user’s `umask` value (whereas the other options will only override requested parts of the user’s umask value).
>     Examples: `0660` will make the repo read/write-able for the owner and group, but inaccessible to others (equivalent to group unless `umask` is e.g. `0022`).
>     `0640` is a repository that is group-readable but not group-writable. See git-init(1).
>
> **False by default**.

Comment: ok so essentially the git config will choose the permissions in this manner, no matter what?

Comment: @sbartell: that is the idea, overriding the user default's umask.

Comment: This is the way to go. What I didn't realize at the time of writing this question was that windows server was forcing read only permissions (except for admins) on any files placed in it. So any thing I pull would be read only. That explains that.